# 2 Independent MsgBoxs for single cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Have defined 3 Value limits: A, A1 and B for one cell.  I already have a MsgBox to warn of being outside range A:B.  I need another MsgBox to caution of being between A:A1  Any way of displaying 2 independent messages with Excel Data Validation, or a way of coding in VBA for a single cell? Thanks.

Comment: Not with `Range.DataValidation`, no. Data validation error messages, as strongly hinted by the UI, don't support different messages for different rule violations. Either you craft the error message to encompass all violations, or you remove the DV error message and use a `Worksheet_Change` handler to show different messages given different conditions.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll research the Worksheet_Change workaround.